Spring Boot RestClient as a singleton or create new instances per request
Looking through the documentation here, the expected pattern to use for RestClient is to autowire the RestClient.Builder and then build the RestClient in the constructor method of a service. While this works great when using in a regular class, it does not work as well when testing.
According to the documentation here, the @RestClientTest and @AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer are usable when there is only 1 builder used within your application. As more instances are created and specific customization is needed, it becomes apparent that you will want to have more than one RestClient.Builder for each specific service.
With this, the only way that I can see to configure it is to bind the MockRestServiceServer to each RestClient.Builder making having them as beans seem to be the obvious route. Now you can have some code like the following:
Configuration logic:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfiguration {
    private final RestClientBuilderConfigurer restClientBuilderConfigurer;

    @Bean
    RestClient.Builder microservice1RestClientBuilder() {
        return createDefaultRestClientBuilder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8081");
    }

    /**
     * Copied from
     * {@link org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestClientAutoConfiguration
     * RestClientAutoConfiguration}
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private RestClient.Builder createDefaultRestClientBuilder() {
        RestClient.Builder builder = RestClient
                .builder()
                .requestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings.DEFAULTS));
        return restClientBuilderConfigurer.configure(builder);
    }
}

Controller logic:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class MainController {
    private final MainService mainService;

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return mainService.helloService();
    }
}

Service logic:
@Service
public class MainService {
    private final RestClient restClient;
    
    public MainService(RestClient.Builder microservice1RestClientBuilder) {
        super();
        restClient = microservice1RestClientBuilder.build();
    }

    public String helloService() {
        return restClient.get().uri("/").retrieve().body(String.class);
    }
}

Test logic:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MainControllerTest {
    private MockRestServiceServer microservice1Server;

    @Autowired
    private RestClient.Builder microservice1RestClientBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        microservice1Server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(microservice1RestClientBuilder).build();
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        microservice1Server
                .expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8081/"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("Hello world", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful()).andExpect(content().string("Hello world"));
    }
}

This all seems like it should work, but it does not because the test will not bind before the RestClient is created. To fix this, the service class can be changed to the following and the test will begin to work.
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MainService {
    private final RestClient.Builder microservice1RestClientBuilder;

    public String helloService() {
        return microservice1RestClientBuilder.build().get().uri("/").retrieve().body(String.class);
    }
}

The test case works now however the RestClient is now created per call which feels unnecessary. This makes me believe either I am missing how it is expected to be used or there is a gap somewhere. My hope with this question is to show the optimal way to use RestClient not only for general usage but also for testing purposes.

You are correct that @AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer will not work in cases like this. It looks like you will have the best luck using MockServerRestClientCustomizer. The javadoc for the class shows an example of its usage, and there is an integration test case that can also be used as an example.
With this technique, your test class might look something like this:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MainControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MainService mainService;

    @Autowired
    private MockServerRestClientCustomizer customizer;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class MainControllerTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        MockServerRestClientCustomizer mockServerRestClientCustomizer() {
            return new MockServerRestClientCustomizer();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        this.customizer.getServer(this.mainService.getRestClientBuilder())
                .expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8081/"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("Hello world", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

        mvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(content().string("Hello world"));
    }
}


That seems to work perfectly however for whatever reason if you use the builder for more than one test, the second test would fail.  I added @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD and that fixed it. The error without it is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add more expectations after actual requests are made".  I'll mark this as the answer though as this does fix the problem but if you could reply back with some info on why it may be failing.

Thanks @AnthonyLofton  for editing my mocked-up code example to make it more correct.

When using the auto-configured MockRestServerService, the expectations automatically get reset after each test. With the MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer, they also get reset automatically in most cases. That's not happening right now with the MockServerRestClientCustomizer. I'll look into how we might be able to make that happen. In the meantime, it might be simpler to write an @AfterEach method in your test class that does this.customizer.getExpectationManagers().values().forEach(RequestExpectationManager::reset); instead of @DirtiesContext.

Sounds good thanks for the great explinations! I have a much better understanding now.

I discovered you can also do this.customizer.getServer().reset(). That's much simpler than iterating over the expectation managers. At the least, we'll add some documentation for this somewhere.

Looks like you have to call that reset on each server for it to work appropriately. Going through the ExpectationManagers seems to be more effective when you have lots of RestClientBuilders at a glance.

Just looked a bit deeper and found there is a getServers() so looks like running this works fine: customizer.getServers().values().forEach(MockRestServiceServer::reset)
